# Give an example of a real function so that every rational is a strict local minimum

Tags: functional-analysis, contest-math

> Give an example of $f : \mathbb R → [0, \infty) $ so that every $r \in \mathbb Q$ is
>   a strict local minimum for $f$.

*Strict local minimum means there is a vicinity* $V$ *of* $r$ *such that* $f(y) > f(r) ,\ \forall y \in V-\{r\}$

---

**My attempt**

So far, none. My feeling is there isn't such a function, mainly because of the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. Suppose I define $f$ like this: $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \not \in \mathbb Q$. Every rational $r$ does not map to a strict local minimum for $f$ only because of the other rationals present in every vicinity of $r$. So $f$ cannot be constant on $\mathbb Q$, but how to define it is beyond my imagination.

Comment: My first Google hit for "local minimum at all rational numbers" was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function which – I think – can be modified to fit your needs by considering $1 - f(x)$.

Comment: @MartinR more of a meta topic, but is Googling advised?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you are right, 1 - (Thomae's function) is such an example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a pretty direct hint. If there were only rationals, the function could be defined as the denominator in lowest terms, because everything nearby enough would have a larger denominator. If we want to also define it on the irrationals this wouldn't work. However, we can compress the positive integers into $[0,1)$ in an order preserving way, then we can make the function $1$ on the irrationals.

Comment: I like this answer better because it explains some of the reasoning.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the function that sends any irrational number on $1$ and sends a rational $\frac{p}q$ (where the fraction is irreducible) on $1-\frac1q$ does the job. Given any rational number $\frac{p}q$, you can always find a neighborhood so that any rational number has a denominator bigger than $q$

Comment: The function needs to be nonnegative.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Then add $1$ ...

Comment: @H. Potter perhaps $1$ and $1-\frac 1 q$

Comment: @MattSamuel There are many ways to change the function so that it becomes nonnegative. Find your favorite one :)

Comment: Can you make it nonnegative (with 1 - whatever), to accept your answer, please?

Comment: @EugenCovaci done, thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure is OK for the function to send any irrational number on 0? Because any irrational becomes global minimum of this function.

Comment: @EugenCovaci haha just corrected without looking at what I wrote. Now it should be ok !